# What is the reason for MultiHeadAttention having a different call convention than Attention and AdditiveAttention?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model, multihead-attention

`Attention` and `AdditiveAttention` [are called with their input tensors in a list](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/68f9af408a1734704746f7e6fa9cfede0d6879d8/keras/layers/attention/base_dense_attention.py#L160). (same as `Add`, `Average`, `Concatenate`, `Dot`, `Maximum`, `Multiply`, `Subtract`)

But `MultiHeadAttention` [is called by passing the input tensors as separate arguments](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/68f9af408a1734704746f7e6fa9cfede0d6879d8/keras/layers/attention/multi_head_attention.py#L549-L550).

The following minimal example shows the difference in how the `inbound_nodes` are linked:

```py
import json

from tensorflow.keras.layers import AdditiveAttention, Attention, Input, MultiHeadAttention
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inputs = [Input(shape=(8, 16)), Input(shape=(4, 16))]
outputs = [Attention()([inputs[0], inputs[1]]),
           AdditiveAttention()([inputs[0], inputs[1]]),
           MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=2, key_dim=2)(inputs[0], inputs[1])]
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(model.to_json()), indent=4))
```

```
[...]
                "name": "attention",
                "inbound_nodes": [
                    [
                        [
                            "input_1",
                            0,
                            0,
                            {}
                        ],
                        [
                            "input_2",
                            0,
                            0,
                            {}
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
[...]
                "name": "additive_attention",
                "inbound_nodes": [
                    [
                        [
                            "input_1",
                            0,
                            0,
                            {}
                        ],
                        [
                            "input_2",
                            0,
                            0,
                            {}
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
[...]
                "name": "multi_head_attention",
                "inbound_nodes": [
                    [
                        [
                            "input_1",
                            0,
                            0,
                            {
                                "value": [
                                    "input_2",
                                    0,
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
[...]
```

What's the reason for `MultiHeadAttention` not following the convention of the other two attention layers, and what does it mean for `input_2` being stored as `value` in `input_1` in the `inbound_nodes`?

(Some context on why this is relevant to me: I'm maintaining [this library](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) and would like to implement support for `MultiHeadAttention`.)

Comment: Well, I only spotted the difference between these 3 layers in the mask argument. Attention and AdditiveAttention accept mask as a list for both query and values, while MultiheadAttention accepts mask as single array for query only.

Comment: @user2586955 I'm not sure if I correctly understand what you mean. In my code example, the first two layers take their two input tensors as one (list) argument, while the third layer takes two (single-tensor) arguments. So there is a difference even when not using a mask.

Comment: I did some git archeology, and found the original commit adding [AdditiveAttention](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b81c4dbcee04d074c9300f71ad52b4dfd1c6ebce), and the commit adding [MultiHeadAttention](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f32c80b3ed0d64eb0363f4196171467de79390d1). (It's in the tensorflow repo because this change predates keras having its own repo.)

Comment: @NickODell Thanks. So this [difference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b81c4dbcee04d074c9300f71ad52b4dfd1c6ebce#diff-df45f4182780bab999e120b4c3d29930c12d980424f9e4f592628342af2022fdR318) [existed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f32c80b3ed0d64eb0363f4196171467de79390d1#diff-ba7ff9314dc55fb00c9bd560bd52484ab346187108efa648906163e615f30aeeR435) right from the start.